# Validate the add to cart button in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new here and looking for some help. I have used the below code in order to change the add to cart button with quantity. The dropdown starts from 0 to 20. So I would like to add a validation to the button when someone clicks on add button with a 0 qty selected. So can you please help me in validating the 0?

Code used for the dropdown:

```
function woocommerce_quantity_input() {
    global $product;

    $defaults = array(
        'input_name'    => 'quantity',
        'input_value'   => '1',
        'max_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
        'min_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
        'step'      => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
        'style'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left; margin-right:5px;', $product )
    );
    if ( ! empty( $defaults['min_value'] ) )
        $min = $defaults['min_value'];
    else $min = 0;

    if ( ! empty( $defaults['max_value'] ) )
        $max = $defaults['max_value'];
    else $max = 20;

    if ( ! empty( $defaults['step'] ) )
        $step = $defaults['step'];
    else $step = 1;

    $options = '';
    for ( $count = $min; $count <= $max; $count = $count+$step ) {
        $options .= '<option value="' . $count . '">' . $count . '</option>';
    }
    echo '<div class="quantity_select" style="' . $defaults['style'] . '"><select name="' . esc_attr( $defaults['input_name'] ) . '" title="' . _x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) . '" class="qty">' . $options . '</select></div>';
}
```

Comment: There are built in function hooks and filters for this please study woocome documentation

Comment: i am trying to find the validation hooks in the woo commerce document. no luck so far can you please help me how to do this as i am not a developer but trying to build a website with validations. i tried many things but no luck. please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation you can check the how wordpress sanitization work

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-input/